# Почему не сортируется массив

Tags: c++, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Добрый день! Тренирую алгоритмы сортировки на C++, и наткнулся на такую проблему:

Я создаю массив из `X` элементов, данный `X` я ввожу через клавиатуру. Все это проводится в методе **`main()`**

```
int length;
cout << "How many elements do you want to add? Type here: ";
cin >> length;
int array[length];
```

После ввода `X` заполняю свой массив с длинной `X` случайными числами. И вывожу на экран:

```
cout << "Your current array is:\n\n";
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
array[i] = rand() % 100;
printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

Ну после чего мы видим **не отсортированный** массив..

Далее я создаю метод который принимает в параметрах наш массив с моими элементами и сортирует методом пузырька

```
void sort(int array[]){
    int length, temp, j;
    length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    bool sort = true;
    while(sort){
        j++;
        sort = false;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < length - j; i++){
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]){
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = temp;
                sort = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и в **`main()`** методе вызываю данный метод..

```
main(){
    //declare array
    sort(array);
    //output after sorting
}
```

Но когда я запускаю программу я вижу что массив мой не отсортирован.. Где у меня ошибка? 
Знаю что если в Java написать такую реализацию, то она будет работать.. Но как я понял только что, в С++ по другому надо.

Comment: не используйте printf используйте cout

Comment: @JK_Action Да я знаю, просто printf удобен немного)

Comment: По изучал вопрос пришел к мнению что был не прав.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ не поддерживает массивы переменной длины. Существуют отдельные компиляторы, которые имеют собственные расширения языка C++, включающие такую поддержку, но лучше на это не полагаться. Так что данный код

```
int length;
cout << "How many elements do you want to add? Type here: ";
cin >> length;
int array[length];
```

не соответствует стандарту C++.

Вам следует динамически распределить массив. Например,

```
int *array = new int[length];
```

и по завершению работы программы его удалить

```
delete [] array;
```

При передачи массива по значению в качестве аргумента функции он неявно преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент. Поэтому данное объявление функции

```
void sort(int array[]);
```

эквивалентно следующему объявлению функции

```
void sort(int *array);
```

и объявляют одну и ту же функции.

Внутри этой функции

```
void sort(int array[]){
    int length, temp, j;
    length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    //...
```

предложение

```
    length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
```

не вычисляет число элементов в массиве, как вы думаете. Оно эквивалентно следующему предложению

```
    length = sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int );
```

Например, если размер указателя `sizeof( int * )`  равен 8, а размер `sizeof( int )` равно 4, то в результате вы получите 2.

Вам  следует объявить функцию как

```
void sort( int array[], int length );
```

или еще лучше как

```
void sort( int array[], size_t length );
```

Что касается пузырьковой сортировки, то смотрите [мой ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393035/write-a-program-that-uses-bubble-sort-to-sort-integers-in-a-2-dimensional-array/39393312#39393312)
Помимо всего прочего в вашей функции вы используете **не инициализированную** переменную `j`, что ведет к неопределенному поведению программы

```
int length, temp, j;
                 ^^^
length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
bool sort = true;
while(sort){
    j++;
    ^^^^
```

Обратите внимание, что функция main без параметров должна объявляться в C++ как

```
int main()
^^^
```

Comment: Вау) Все так понятно и ясно) Да мой стиль кода больше на Java похож... я на C++ только неделю как начал работать, и какие тут правила и как нужно писать не знаю)) И все это для скучных лабораторных работ... А насчет переменно `j` я тут забыл 0 поставить) В программе 0 стоит)

Answer (score 2):

Как вы сами догадались, ваша главная(но не единственная) проблема в том, что вы неправильно вычислили размер массива. Если вы напишете вывод в консоль значения переменной `length`, то сразу это увидите. У меня, например, оно всегда равно двум.

Теперь как с этим быть. Вы сейчас, по сути, передаете в функцию указатель на начало массива. Получить при таком раскладе число элементов - никак.

Один выход вы уже нашли. Передавать указатель на начало и размер:

```
void sort(int *array, int size){
//...
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    sort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
}
```

Можно поступить в стиле стандартной библиотеки и передавать указатель на первый и на следующий за последним элементы:

```
void sort(int *begin, int *end){
//...
}

int main(){
    int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    sort(&arr[0], &arr[4]);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что `&arr[4]` возвращает указатель на несуществующий элемент. Его нельзя разыменовывать. Но для того, чтобы обозначить конец массива, он вполне сгодится.

Ну и путь для крутых парней :). Ссылка на массив + шаблоны:

```
template<int size>
void sort(int (&array)[size]){
//...
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    sort(arr);
}
```

Уверен на начальном этапе вам не стоит забивать этим голову, но согласитесь, выглядит круто. Компилятор сам вывел размер массива, нам даже делать ничего не пришлось.

Comment: Хах)) Согласен) Выглядит и вправду круто) Но я не хочу внедряться глубже в C++, я привык что в Java есть готовые классы где можно взять и написать `array.length` и не надо заморачиваться с его длинной) А тут чтоб узнать его длину нужно магией заниматься) Да и все равно) главное что проблема решена) и все довольны :))

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, такие классы есть и в С++. `std::vector`(`ArrayList` в java), `std::list`(`LinkedList` в java), `std::set`(`TreeSet` в java), `std::map`(`TreeMap` в java), `std::unordered_set`(`HashSet` в java), `std::unordered_map`(`HashMap` в java). Есть еще `std::unordered_mulimap`, `std::mulimap`, `std::unordered_muliset` и `std::muliset`, но я затрудняюсь назвать их аналоги в java